# Photoshop select layer by name

Tags: javascript, photoshop

In photoshop for some reason when I try select a layer by name, in the console

```
activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Layer1');


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByName' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:20
```

What's is causing this error? Every bit of code that I find to help just gives the same error.

Comment: `activeDocument.artLayers` is undefined use debugger to see value of activeDocument and activeDocument.artLayers

Comment: Where do you run this? This code is supposed to be run on host side but the error looks like you're running it from somewhere else

Comment: The codes being run inside the console of the debugger

Comment: Of what debugger..?

Comment: Have you tried "Layer 1" with a space?

Comment: @GhoulFool if the layer isn't there it'd through a 'no such element' error. I think OP tries to execute the code in UXP console or in CEP console

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy You're right it'll pop up error 1302 no such element. I just noticed the absence of the space which might be causing further complications.

Comment: Yes, the code is being executed inside the UXP debug console

The layer in the doc is 'Layer1' with no space but it fails for any layer name

Comment: Voila. This is not uxp code, this is jsx code. Check the UXP API for proper syntax https://www.adobe.io/photoshop/uxp/guides/ps_basics#layer

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction - invaluable for someone learning